# Set of discontinuity points of a cdf: accumulation points.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

A cumulative distribution function (cdf) has a countable set of discontinuity points. They need not be isolated. Let us call non-isolated points 'accumulation points' of this set of discontinuity points. Is it possible that a cdf admits also countably infinite accumulation points in its set of discontinuity points? If so, is this something as pathological as requiring a singular distribution or it can also happen with discrete distributions?

Thanks for any clarification, it would be nice to have concrete examples.

Comment: Suppose $r_{n}$ is an enumeration of rationals in $\Bbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ with $r_{1}=0$ Then you can define $F(x)=\sum_{n:r_{n}\leq x}\frac{1}{2^{n}}$. Then this is a cdf which is discontinuous at all rationals.  The corresponding distribution is just given by $\mu(\{0\})=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\mu(\{r_{n}\})=\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ for $r\geq 1$.

Comment: thank you, then by the density of the rationals every discontinuity point is not isolated.